# How to pass printer settings while print bulk pdfs

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, printing, vbscript

I have used the following code: -

```
 Process objP = new Process();
 objP.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\pdfs\\A007D_EDIQ61281.pdf";
 // FileName(.pdf) to print.
 //objP.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(strFilePath);
 objP.StartInfo.WindowStyle =
 ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //Hide the window.
 objP.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
 objP.StartInfo.Arguments = "/p /h " + "C:\\pdfs\\A007D_EDIQ61281.pdf" + " " + "KONICA MINOLTA 190f GDI";
 objP.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;//!! Don't create a Window.
 objP.Start();
 objP.CloseMainWindow();
 MessageBox.Show("All done");
```

But how do pass settings in the arguments like - staple or duplex or portrait/lanscape.
I have also looked into this post - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6899/Changing-printer-settings-using-C  but it is not helping much as I have no idea how to combine these 2

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to tell you a generic answer. In the end it really depends on the program associated with the "print" verb and how it interprets parameters (and which ones it accepts).

You can't combine both methods (yours and the one linked), as your approach depends on an external program, while the linked example prints the document on its own (you'd have to write your own "import filter" (don't do it)).

You could however use a premade/third party library. Some are linked under **Related** on the right side of this page.